# How to fix 'Cast to embedded failed for value' error in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have created a schema for users and in that schema i have one of the properties as 'orders' whose value is set to another schema. I'm unable to update documents in 'orders' property. It shows an error saying 'Casting to embedded failed "{ orderNumber: 6788444,\n  orderDate: \'30-08-2018\',\n  orderedItem: { name: \'Gamepad\' },\n  price: 599 }" at path "orders". '

I initially thought the problem was occurring because of using 'findByIdAndUpdate' but that was not the problem. Later, instead of setting the 'orders' value to another schema i set all the values in the property itself but it didn't work.

Here is the  userSchema and ordersSchema:-

```
import {Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';
import * as  mongoose from 'mongoose';

interface userInfo extends Document{
    name: string,
    username: string,
    password: string,
    orders : [{
        orderNumber: string,
        orderDate: string | Date,
        orderedItem: {
            name: string
        },
        price: number
    }],
    email: string,
    address: string,
    subscription: boolean
}

let orderSchema : Schema = new Schema({
    orderNumber: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    orderDate:{
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    orderedItem: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})

let userSchema : Schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type:String
    },
    subscription:{
        type: Boolean
    },
    orders: [orderSchema]
});

let UserModel = mongoose.model<userInfo>('User', userSchema);


export {UserModel};
```

And here is the code of where I'm trying to update the sub document:-

```
import {UserModel} from '../models/user';
import * as express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

router.put('/newOrder/:id', async(req: Request, res: Response)=> {
    let newOrder = {
        orderNumber: req.body.orderNumber,
        orderDate: req.body.orderDate,
        orderedItem: req.body.orderedItem,
        price: req.body.price
     };



    const user = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$push:{orders: newOrder}}, {new: true});

    res.send(user);

})
```

Here are the values i gave in Postman:-

```
{
    "orderNumber": 6788444,
    "orderDate": "30-08-2018",
    "orderedItem": {
        "name": "Gamepad"
    },
    "price": 599

}
```

The error is " CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "{ orderNumber: 6788444,\n  orderDate: \'30-08-2018\',\n  orderedItem: { name: \'Gamepad\' },\n  price: 599 }" at path "orders"   "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your userInfo interface, the datatype of orderNumber is specified as a string.

```
interface userInfo extends Document{
    name: string,
    username: string,
    password: string,
    orders : [{
        orderNumber: string,
        orderDate: string | Date,
        orderedItem: {
            name: string
        },
        price: number
    }],
    email: string,
    address: string,
    subscription: boolean
}
```

whereas in your orderSchema it is specified as a Number.
Change the datatype in your interface to number

```
orders : [{
        orderNumber: number,
        orderDate: string | Date,
        orderedItem: {
            name: string
        },
        price: number
    }]
```

That should work.